# Over Engineering: Using reference (borrow?) on HashMap key in Rust

Tags: rust, hashmap, micro-optimization

I'm making a search algorithm (BFS/DFS) to search a tree of game states.
I already made the thing in C, but I was wondering if Rust would be faster, and since I've been meaning to learn Rust anyway I figured I would give it a shot.

I'm trying to optimize this thing to the point of over engineering (I like it, let me be), and I have made an optimization in C that I thought was cool, but I can't figure out how to (/if it is possible) in Rust.

The outline of my algorithm is this:

```
Add the start state to a queue, and make a hashmap [State -> Previous State, Action]
// I use this hashmap to find the way back later, and to check if I have been in a state before.

Take a state S0 from the queue:
   for all possible actions, calculate next state S1:
      if S1 is already a key in the hashmap, continue
      and add [ S1 -> S0, action taken ] to the hashmap
      add S1 to the queue,
   ...
   // some other stuff here to check when to stop
```

One of the optimizations I did in C was this: Instead of copying the state struct data into the queue, I copy a pointer to that same data in the hashmap (since I just added it to the hashmap anyway) into the queue, this way I don't have to copy the state data, but the queue just consists of pointers to the same data in the hashmap.

This works easily in C because I have my own hashmap implementation, so it was easy to make a function to return the pointer to the right data in the hashmap.

In Rust I now have this:

```
// Add all possible moves to be searched through later
for m in possible_moves.iter() {
    if let Some(new_state) = popped.do_move(m) { // popped is S0 from my algorithm outline
        if backmap.contains_key(&new_state) { continue; }
        queue.push_back(new_state);
        backmap.insert(new_state, Wayback {
        prev_state: popped, did_move: m });
    }
}
```

But this means that the new_state data is copied into the queue and the hashmap.
I wonder if there is a way to not copy this data in Rust, like my C version (or some other way).

I would like this optimization because I just like the optimized feeling of it, but in Rust's case also because right now this copy means that I have `#[derive(Clone, Copy)]` above all my structs, which is just not nice imo, if there is not a way to do my over-engineered optimization, but there is a way to not have to derive to copy and clone traits I would still like to know.

Thank you very much for any help!

P.S. I recognize that this is not your regular code question, and it might be quite unclear from my explanation, so if there is any questions about what I mean, I will answer them asap.

Comment: If you directly translated this code into C, but only stored a pointer to `new_state` in the hashmap, then the hashmap would contain a dangling pointer on the next loop iteration. It may happen to just work because you never dereference it, but I think that's still techniically UB - at least it is in Rust.

Comment: Actually yes, if there was a hash collision the hashmap might do an equality comparison with the dangling pointer. UB.

Comment: Actually, I copy a pointer *to* the data in the hashmap into the queue, and nothing in the hashmap is removed or overwritten until this whole algorithm is done and the memory is discarded, so no dangling pointers for me, the hashmap contains all the data, the queue would have a dangling pointer if I removed something from the hashmap

Comment: 1. the compiler can't really know whether you're removing data from the hashmap, that's not part of its "model" so it can't optimistically know or assume you're *not* removing stuff, 2. more problematically when you insert a key if the hashmap has exceeded its load factor it may [non-incrementally resize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Resizing_by_copying_all_entries) which moves every entry, and 3. even more problematically depending on the [collision resolution algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Robin_Hood_hashing) any insert could move any existing entry.

Comment: This is not theoretical by the way, while I have not looked at how collision resolution works in hashbrown (/ swisstable) the previous iteration of HashMap used robin hood hashing.

Comment: @Masklinn if you are talking about Rust using those things, then I guess you answered my question on why it is not possible though I do still have the question about if it is then possible to get rid of the "#[derive(Clone, Copy)]" above my structs somehow

Answer (score 0):

> I would like this optimization because I just like the optimized feeling of it, but in Rust's case also because right now this copy means that I have #[derive(Clone, Copy)] above all my structs, which is just not nice imo

Depending on the size of the struct… does it actually matter? a `Copy` is just a `memcpy`.

> if there is not a way to do my over-engineered optimization, but there is a way to not have to derive to copy and clone traits I would still like to know.

The problem here is that Rust wants a clear static owner for each piece of data, but that doesn't exist in your algorithm: the state is "owned" by both the map and the queue. The way to "share" unclear ownership is to use an `Rc`, but that translates into a heap allocation (the refcount traffic doesn't really matter when it's not atomic), which would probably be a pessimisation if `state`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I get that Rust wants a clear owner for each piece of data, but is that not the case in my solution? The way I see it is that the hashmap would own the data, and the queue would own a reference to the data in the hashmap, or is that not how it works in Rust? (sorry, new to Rust)

Comment: Technically yes, the issue is that Rust references operate on a strict R^W basis, so you'd insert a key in the hashmap, get a reference to the key, which would borrow the hashmap. Next loop around the hashmap is still borrowed (it has an outstanding reference) and you can't insert into it, because that requires a mutable reference to the hashmap which can't coexist alongside the existing immutable reference. It even makes complete sense: on any insert (or removal) the hashmap can resize, which moves every key and value, which invalidates outstanding references.